# Only allow one image at the same time with File API?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

Only allow one image at the same time with File API?
What's the correct method to set the restriction for only one image at the same time?

```html
<input id="browse" type="file" multiple>
<div id="imgs"></div>

<style type="text/css">
  #imgs {
    height: imageheight;
    width: imagewidth;
    position: absolute;
    top: 39px;
    left: 9px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var elBrowse = document.getElementById("browse"),
    elPic = document.getElementById("imgs"),
    useBlob = false && window.URL;

  function readImage(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {

      var image = new Image();
      image.addEventListener("load", function() {
        elPic.appendChild(this);
      });

      image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function() {

    var files = this.files; {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if ((/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name)) {

          readImage(file);
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the multiple attribute from the file input? Or maybe I am not understanding your intentions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be a promise chain like this:

```
function readImage(file) {
  //wrap readImage body into a promise
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {

      var image = new Image();
      image.addEventListener("load", function () {
        elPic.appendChild(this);
        //resolve the promise after the child is appended so the caller would know when to start the next one
        resolve();
      });

      image.src = useBlob ? window.URL.createObjectURL(file) : reader.result;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}

elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function () {

  var files = this.files; {
    //start the chain
    var chain = Promise.resolve();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      //use let to have properly scoped variable
      let file = files[i];
      if ((/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name)) {
        //append functions to call to the chain
        chain = chain.then(() => readImage(file));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The call to the next readImage() is performed after resolve() is called in the previous one - after the image is loaded and appended.

You might want to consider using loadend event also, it is emitted even when the loading fails for some reason so it won't break your chain.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadend

Comment: I tried the promise chain solution, but then the loading routine will fail for some reason.

Comment: No errors are present, but the image will not show up with promise chain implemented. I wonder why though. Actually there must be a way to implement the new restriction for one image without loosing the main function. Otherwise I could use a short solution with jQuery for the upload, which is something I prefer to avoid this time.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. The only issue was that file had to be declared with `let` instead of `var` otherwise it uploaded the same file multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes - it works properly in Chrome now.

Answer (score 0):

I started a new approach that leads to the desired result.

```html
<body style="margin:8px">
<img style="position:absolute; top:39px; left:9px"
     height="imageheight" width="imagewidth">

<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function previewFile() {
   var preview = document.querySelector('img');
   var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
   var reader  = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
     }, false);
     if ((/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i).test(file.name)) {
   reader.readAsDataURL(file); }
 }
</script>
```